# how can get the formula of a data table in excell_

Tags: excel

this is my data and im trying to get the formula of it, how can i do it ( it dosent have to be using excell only but i dont know how to do it )

```
    0   2       4       6       8
0   100 90      80      70      60
2   85  64.49   53.5    48.15   50
4   70  48.9    38.43   35.03   40
6   55  38.78   30.39   27.07   30
8   40  35      30      25      20
```

and this is the graphic that i obtain
[image]

but when i try to do an adjustment of the data i cant find the option as in a 2d graph

[image]

Comment: You want a surface fit (2D curve fit)?

Comment: i wanted 3D one, but i was only able to do it in 2d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i didnt find how to get the equation for those values but this problem its solved by the bilinear interpolation
i used this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=va8vFViss90
and this calculator to make sure that i didnt messed it up https://www.ajdesigner.com/phpinterpolation/bilinear_interpolation_equation.php#ajscroll